# Characterizing steady-states of $dx/dt = x(y^2 - y)$, $dy/dt = x - y$ using the Jacobian matrix.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to characterize the steady-states of the following system of differential equations:
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= x(y^2 - y) \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= x- y
\end{align*}
I found the steady-states for this system to be $(0,0)$ and $(1, 1)$, and found the Jacobian matrix to be
$$J(x, y) = \begin{pmatrix}y^2 - y & x(2y - 1) \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Let's just look at the steady state $(0, 0)$. Then we have $J(0,0) = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$, and we can define
\begin{align*}
\beta &= \text{Tr} \; J(0,0) = -1 \\
\gamma &= \text{det} \; J(0, 0) = 0
\end{align*}

So, here's where I'm running into a problem. The book I have gives the following criteria for determining the qualitative nature of steady states:

- Unstable node: $\beta > 0$ and $\gamma > 0$.
- Saddle point: $\gamma < 0$.
- Stable node: $\beta < 0$ and $\gamma > 0$.
- Unstable spiral: $\beta^2 < 4\gamma$ and $\beta > 0$.
- Neutral center: $\beta^2 < 4\gamma$ and $\beta = 0$.
- Stable spiral: $\beta^2 < 4\gamma$ and $\beta < 0$.

The values of $\beta$ and $\gamma$ that I found for $(0, 0)$ don't seem to fit into any of these categories, so how can I characterize the steady state?

Comment: In general it might be better to look at the eigenvalues of the matrix. If the real parts of all eigenvalues are negative, then it is stable. Any positive real part will make it unstable. Complex eigenvalues would make it a spiral. And a real part of zero you could call neutral (however repeated zeroes can also be unstable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with $(1,1)$, look carefully at your table.

Point $(0,0)$ cannot be characterized by linearization. To actually figure out what happening around this point a more subtle approach is necessary (e.g., you can find a center manifold and study dynamics on it.)

Anyway, for you system point $(0,0)$ is a so-called saddle-node non-hyperbolic point.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I suppose I wasn't aware that there could be points where the system couldn't be linearized.